# Android Studio - 4K monitor UI scaling

Tags: android, android-studio

The latest update to 141 made all the icons really tiny. I do see much improved sharpness in fonts which is really nice and it makes me think the devs have added support for 4k displays but **I cannot find any relevant options to scale up the UI.** Any ideas how to scale up the UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot

It says to add:

```
hidpi = true
```

in your Customize your IDE properties (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#customize_ide)